# "Tint" property when drawing Image with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, gdi

Given a color, how can I "tint" an image when I am drawing it into a picturebox with VB.NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [ColorMatrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class to accomplish this:

```
    'Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Tints a bitmap using the specified color and intensity.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="b">Bitmap to be tinted</param>
    ''' <param name="color">Color to use for tint</param>
    ''' <param name="intensity">Intensity of the tint.  Good ranges are .25 to .75, depending on your preference.  Most images will white out around 2.0. 0 will not tint the image at all</param>
    ''' <returns>A bitmap with the requested Tint</returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
Private function TintBitmap(b As Bitmap, color As Color, intensity As Single ) As Bitmap         
        Dim b2 As New Bitmap(b.Width,b.Height)

        Dim ia As New ImageAttributes

        Dim m As ColorMatrix 
        m = New ColorMatrix(New Single()() _
            {New Single() {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, _
             New Single() {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, _
             New Single() {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, _
             New Single() {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, _
             New Single() {color.R/255*intensity, color.G/255*intensity, color.B/255*intensity, 0, 1}})

        ia.SetColorMatrix(m)
        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(b2)
        g.DrawImage(b,new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height), 0, 0, b.Width, b.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia)
        Return b2

End Function
```

Then to use it, you can simply:

```
Dim b As Bitmap = New Bitmap(ofd.FileName)                        
PictureBox1.Image = TintBitmap(b,Color.Red,0.3)
```

Comment: This sounds very good. One question: what if I am actually drawing some stuff in the picturebox in the Paint() method, and I'd like *that* stuff to be tinted by this? I believe that your method relies on an actual picture, but I don't have any: I am instead drawing rectangles and such in the picturebox

Comment: You could pass the image of what you have already drawn, so you could call PictureBox1.Image = TintBitmap(PictureBox1.Image,Color.Red, 0.3)

Comment: I'm having a problem: apparently, PictureBox1.Image is *Nothing*, so it throws an error. This is weird. It is true that PictureBox1 doesn't have an image set, but I am definitely drawing stuff on its *Graphics* property. In fact, I am calling *TintBitmap* at the end of *PictureBox1*'s *Paint()* method.

Comment: You can either use this code when drawing directly to the picturebox or draw to a bitmap and assign that to the picturebox's image property.

Comment: Well, if I use this code when drawing directly to the picturebox, what value am I supposed to use when using *g.DrawImage(b,new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height), 0, 0, b.Width, b.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia)* if I need an *Image* type value when I got none? Perhaps I can make an image with code by first making a *Bitmap* object - however, how can I draw rectangles and such to a *Bitmap* if it isn't a *Graphics* type object?

Comment: You can use Graphics.FromImage() method to get a graphics object from a bitmap/image

Comment: Thank you, this is working great. One question: if I also wanted to change the Saturation of the image, is it possible to do through this method as well?

Comment: Probably just upping some of the multipliers in the first three rows of the matrix.  If you can't get it working, ask as another question.

Answer (score 2):

John Koerner's Function Revised:

(Original Pixel Format and unmanaged resources disposed)

```
    'Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
''' <summary>
''' Tints a bitmap using the specified color and intensity.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="b">Bitmap to be tinted</param>
''' <param name="color">Color to use for tint</param>
''' <param name="intensity">Intensity of the tint.  Good ranges are .25 to .75, depending on your preference.  Most images will white out around 2.0. 0 will not tint the image at all</param>
''' <returns>A bitmap with the requested Tint</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private function TintBitmap(b As Bitmap, color As Color, intensity As Single ) As Bitmap         

    Dim b2 As New Bitmap(b.Width,b.Height, b.PixelFormat)

    Dim ia As New ImageAttributes

    Dim m As ColorMatrix 
    m = New ColorMatrix(New Single()() _
        {New Single() {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, _
         New Single() {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, _
         New Single() {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, _
         New Single() {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, _
         New Single() {color.R/255*intensity, color.G/255*intensity, color.B/255*intensity, 0, 1}})

    ia.SetColorMatrix(m)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(b2)
    g.DrawImage(b,new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height), 0, 0, b.Width, b.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia)


  g.Dispose()
  ia.Dispose()

    Return b2
End Function
```

Don't forget to dispose "b" if you will not use the previous image

Answer (score 0):

Here is the C# implementation, just in case someone needs it.
(Tricky as the 255 int should be explicitly casted to float in order for the color division to return an actual float instead of an int) :

```
Bitmap TintBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Color color, float intensity)
{
    Bitmap outBmp = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, bitmap.PixelFormat);

    using (ImageAttributes ia = new ImageAttributes())
    {

        ColorMatrix m = new ColorMatrix(new float[][]
        {new float[] {1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
         new float[] {0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
         new float[] {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
         new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
         new float[] {color.R/255f*intensity, color.G/255f*intensity, color.B/255f*intensity, 0, 1}});

                ia.SetColorMatrix(m);
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(outBmp))
                    g.DrawImage(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia);
            }

    return outBmp;
}
```